# State-of-the-art techniques for maximizing a differentiable function with multiple local maxima

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization, gradient-flows

Suppose I want to find the global maximum of a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with multiple local maxima, where $n$ is on the order of $100$. I have access to both $f$ and its gradients $\nabla f$. What are the state-of-the-art techniques for solving this problem? Gradient descent alone does not suffice for my problem because it gets stuck in local maxima.

Comment: Use a branch and bound global optimizer, such as BARON https://minlp.com/baron . You will have to try it to determine whether it will succeeds within a tolerable amount of time.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks. Can such an optimizer make use of gradients?

Comment: BARON computes the gradients and all other derivatives it needs internally, based on the user-supplied objective function and constraints.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone What do you think of [optimization by random sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248090/optimization-by-random-sampling) in comparison to this method?

Comment: You'll get no guarantees with random sampling. With a branch and bound global optimizer, at whatever point the optimization is stopped, if the optimizer has found a feasible solution (or you provided it one), there will be a maximum gap between that objective valye and an upper bound (if maximizing). So, for instance, if the best known point has objective value 1.0, and the upper bound is reported as 1.05, you know that point has an objective value no more than 0.05 worse than the global maximum.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone What if you don’t have bounds to work with?

Comment: If you don't have bounds on the variables and the problem is non-convex, that is not easy to deal with. Presuming variables are bounded, the branch and bound optimizer can try to find bounds on the optimal objective value.

Answer (score 1):

this problem is likely unsolvable, sorry :)

Let's say you are looking for a global maximum in a box of length 1 and dimension $m=100$. Further, let's even assume that you know the value of that maximum $F_{\max}$, you just don't know where it is. Let's also assume that the absolute values of all derivatives $|\nabla F|$ are upper-bounded by some number $D$. Whenever you sample one point from the function you get information about whether the maximum might be located within a certain patch localized around the sample point. The exact size and shape of the patch would depend on the value of the function, value of the gradient and $D$. Thing is, you don't get any information on what happens outside that patch. So, in order to guarantee finding the maximum, you must have sufficient patches to cover the entire volume of the cube. The number of patches you need grows exponentially with dimension, so even if you need 2 patches per dimension, you still need $2^{100} \approx 10^{30}$ patches, which is not computable on a regular hardware. Further concerns:

- If you don't know $F_{max}$ or $D$ or the size of the bounding box, you can't even estimate the minimal number of evaluations necessary to guarantee finding maximum.
- You are not only limited by time, but also by storage. Given sufficient problem size remembering what parts of the domain have already been explored becomes an issue.

At least in astronomy, I have seen people use random search (e.g. MCMC) to get the probability distribution of different values occuring in the domain, and then use some prior knowledge to extrapolate the probability distribution to make an educated guess of what the maximum could be. No surprise, depending on prior assumptions and luck, they sometimes are wrong by a few orders of magnitude, but it is not their fault :D

Comment: One can still get bounded rates of convergence. See for instance Proposition 5 (Minimax Rate), Corollary 13 (Upper Bound), and Theorem 15 (Fast Rates) [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02628.pdf).

Comment: I agree. If you know Lipshitz constant of your function, you can estimate convergence rate of an optimization method. It was not obvious from the question that you want to know the convergence rate of the state of the art method. I thought you wanted to use an existing method to find a guaranteed global maximum of a function you have.

Comment: Right. Is there an algorithm that can exploit the differentiable structure of $f$ to get a good convergence?